# iPad can't read text file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity3D project I have several text fields. I saved my text in some text files.

When I test my project on the computer everything works fine, and my code reads the text files. But if I upload to my iPad it won't work and the text fields stay empty.

In the image you can see where I have saved my text files.

[image]

To read my text files I use the following code:

```
public Text infoText;

void Update()
{
    readTextFile("FileName", "StepNumber")
}

public void readTextFile(string fileName, string stepNumber)
{
    StreamReader txt_Reader = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/Text_Files/" + fileName + ".txt");

    while(!txt_Reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string txt_String = txt_Reader.ReadLine();
        if(txt_String.Contains(stepNumber))
        {
            string[] separator = { "_" };
            string[] strList = txt_String.Split(separator, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            infoText.text = string.Join("\n", strList.Skip(1));
        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to change that my iPad can read from the text files?

**EDIT:**

My text files looks like this:

Step 1:
* Some Text
* Some Text

Step 2:
* Some Text
* Some Text
* Some Text

Step 3:
* Some Text

Step 4:
* Some Text

So each `*` should be a new line in my text field. With my old c# code this was no problem, but with

```
var lines = textFiles.text.Split(new char[] { `*` });

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    ...
}
```

i do not know how I can do that, that my text field shows all two lines for step one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all from the [Best Practices for the `Resources` folder](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

> **Don't use it!

Please read the reasons there.

---

In general for system paths do never use simple string concatenation `+ "/" +`!

Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically uses the correct path separators according to the executing platform

```
Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources", "Text_Files", fileName + ".txt");
```

---

However, you don't/can't simply use a `StreamReader` to access the `Resources` folder**s** (See [`Resources` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) since it is packed into the build so you have to go through [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) like

```
// Here you can use / since this is how Unity stores internal paths
// for load you omit the suffix
TextAsset textFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text_Files/" + filename);

string fileContent = textFile.text;
```

Or also have a look at [`Resources.LoadAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html) to not block the main thread meanwhile.

---

#### BUT

Speaking about blocking the main thread: What you definitely do **not** want to do is using any of these within `Update` thus doing heavy FileIO/Loading **every frame**!

Store the content of that file **once** as it won't change afterwards anyway!

---

Depending on your needs you could also simply put your file in any other folder inside the `Assets` and simply use a [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) field directly and drag it into according slot via the Inspector

```
public TextAsset textFile;
```

---

Finally you can then go through the lines one by one using e.g.

```
var lines = textFile.text.Split(new char[]{'/n'});
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that also that `Split` is a quite heavy operation since it has to parse every single character in the string and create new substrings so even store these results somewhere in a field of you need them multiple times during runtime!

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for all the information. But if I try to use `var lines = textFile.text.Split('/n');` I get an error by `Split('/n');` ... says `struct System.Char`

Comment: Yup sorry, c# wants a `char[]` there so let's give it that ^^

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help, but if you see my edit, I am still not able to do it :/

Comment: could figure it how it works .. again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `StreamReader txt_Reader = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/Text_Files/" + fileName + ".txt");` points to a file on your computer. **Assets/Resources/Text_Files/** only exists on your computer.

You need to access a folder that exists on your iPad. It's likely you also didn't save your data to a folder existing on your IPad.

For other devices you could use : `Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName`

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

Comment: You should still not do this! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764234/7111561): **if** you would want to do this you should rather use `Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources", "Text_Files", fileName + ".txt");` However the resources is actually a special case since it is packed into the build and therefore not simply accessible through FileIO.